# How to stop messages like zenpower_read, get_core_current, etc. flooding dmesg output every second?

Tags: linux, amd-ryzen

My dmesg output is full of messages like these:

```
[105096.565468] zenpower_read
[105096.565472] get_ctl_temp
[105096.565474] kernel_smn_read
[105096.565530] zenpower_read
[105096.565531] get_ctl_temp
[105096.565533] kernel_smn_read
```

They serve no useful purpose but appear many times per second, making it extremely hard to monitor dmesg. Just filtering them does not work, for example this command returns nothing in most cases:

```
dmesg | egrep -v '(zenpower_read|kernel_smn_read|plane_to_vcc|zenpower_read|kernel_smn_read|plane_to_vcc|get_ctl_temp|get_soc_current|get_core_current|get_ccd_temp)'
```

So because of these useless messages, I cannot use dmesg command to look at latest kernel messages easily. Also, setting kernel.printk to any values, does not stop these messages, but may suppress useful ones.

I would like to disable these messages forever and never see them again. My understanding they are triggered when something that monitors the CPU temperature is running (AMD Ryzen 9 5950X), which is something I want to have, just without these messages flooding dmesg output.

I tried googling these messages but search results are very few and I found no suggestion how to disable them, so I would appreciate help how to do this.